# How to import facebook account posts in asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

i am in my way to apply my website users to add comment using face book in my account in my website . i have created my app using this link 
and then tried the below code

```
<div id="fb-root" ></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'my API ID',
            status: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

but there is no result and nothing appears to he screen???
any help

Answer (score 0):

You're missing fairly considerable amount of code still... The code you posted will just bring in the Facebook SDK.

Have a look at my comment in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747668/fb-is-undefined-even-though-i-just-used-it/13957616#13957616) which will illustrate how to properly import the SDK.

Once you have it imported, you have to define the HTML in your page to actually place the comment box on the page as well as some other stuff for how it behaves. You're going to want to check out (and sign up for) the Facebook developers page, which offers some useful, yet **seriously** lacking, information on how to load comment blocks, like buttons and how to use OpenGraph stuff. I'd give you the link there, but corporate policy prevents me from accessing Facebook.

Comment: Okay well I'm obviously not going to just code it for you because like I said I don't have access to the documentation but here, this is the first Google result: https://www.google.ca/search?q=how+to+get+facebook+comments+on+your+website&rlz=1C1ASUC_enCA562CA562&oq=how+to+get+facebook+comment&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.9048j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8